# Reading data from CSV

Tags: java, apache, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file. But in first field of my first record I'm getting a space before my string. Anyone could help me?

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fx);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, ENCODING)) {
        final CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withDelimiter(DELIMITER));

        for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
            String cidade = record.get(0);
```

First line of my file is "FUNCHAL;1261;9000;C;D;" and I'm getting " FUNCHAL".
After first line is ok.

Comment: ENCODING is UTF8 and DELIMITER is equal to ";"

Comment: I suppose you could try: `String cidade = record.get(0).trim();`.

Comment: already tried. must be an invisible character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you are reading a file encoding with a BOM marker, possibly a UTF-8 with BOM. Java doesn't strip the marker away and calling `trim()` won't help.

Try parsing with [univocity-parsers](https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) which handles BOM markers properly and is also [3 times faster](https://github.com/uniVocity/csv-parsers-comparison) than commons-csv.

```
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(Csv.parseExcel());
    for(Record record : parser.iterateRecords(fx, ENCODING)){
        record.getString(0);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Abracos

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open source and free (Apache 2.0 license)